# Is there a way to test that custom Gradle plugins configured a project properly?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm developing a custom Gradle plugin and I want to test that it configured properly such as repository, dependency and configuration of target projects.

Any ideas?

Comment: you could check following links related to testing Gradle plugins : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/test_kit.html  ,   https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:writing_tests_for_your_plugin